# Is there a reference in the first line of Madeleine Robins' "Petty Treason"?

Tags: alternate-history, sarah-tolerance

The first lines of Madeleine Robins' three Sarah Tolerance books are as follows:

*Point of Honour*

> It is a truth universally acknowledged that a Fallen Woman of good family must, soon or late, descend to whoredom.

*Petty Treason*

> It is one thing, and a quite considerable thing, to be a lady.

*The Sleeping Partner*

> No one who had seen Miss Sarah Brereton as a child would have taken her for a heroine.

The first and third lines are obvious references to the first sentences of *Pride and Prejudice* and *Northanger Abbey* respectively. The second one doesn't come from the first line of any other Austen book; is it a reference to something else? I've been googling fragments of it, but I haven't come up with anything plausible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no particular reference in the second book.  I tried to come up with a riff on an Austen opening line, but it didn't seem to work.  So I made it up.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: How do we know you're really *the* Madeleine Robins?

Comment: @jwodder - How do you know she's not?